# How can I use pandas to set a value for all rows that match part of a multi part index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> indexes = [['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'd', '1'], ['1', '1', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
>>> pandas.DataFrame(index=indexes, columns=["Year", "Color", "Manufacturer"])
    Year Color Manufacturer
a 1  NaN   NaN          NaN
  1  NaN   NaN          NaN
c 3  NaN   NaN          NaN
d 4  NaN   NaN          NaN
  5  NaN   NaN          NaN
1 6  NaN   NaN          NaN
```

What command could I use to set the Manufacturer column to "Manf X" in all rows that have "1" for their second index value? I've tried the following commands but have not had much luck:

```
set_value((,'1'), "Manufacturer", "Manf X")
set_value((:,'1'), "Manufacturer", "Manf X")
```

It looks like I can use a similar command for setting the column in all rows that have 1 for their first index value, but I just can't get it working when I'm looking to just match on the second index value.

```
set_value(('1',), "Manufacturer", "Manf X")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, using [slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
import pandas as pd
indexes = [['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'd', '1'], ['1', '1', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=indexes, columns=["Year", "Color", "Manufacturer"])

df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df)
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, '1'], ["Manufacturer"]] = "SomeManufacturer"
print(df)
```

Before:

```
    Year Color Manufacturer
1 6  NaN   NaN          NaN
a 1  NaN   NaN          NaN
  1  NaN   NaN          NaN
c 3  NaN   NaN          NaN
d 4  NaN   NaN          NaN
  5  NaN   NaN          NaN
```

After:

```
    Year Color      Manufacturer
1 6  NaN   NaN               NaN
a 1  NaN   NaN  SomeManufacturer
  1  NaN   NaN  SomeManufacturer
c 3  NaN   NaN               NaN
d 4  NaN   NaN               NaN
  5  NaN   NaN               NaN
```

(Sorting the index is required.  Without sorting:)

```
UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'
```